# GWT, Maven - Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: java, windows, maven, gwt, memory

I'm trying to build a GWT project, using Maven. When gwt-maven-plugin tries to compile the code, it throws an error:

```
[ERROR] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
[INFO] Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

I tried `mvn -Dgwt.extraJvmArgs=-Xmx1280m clean install`, it didn't help.

An obvious solution is usually to set `MAVEN_OPTS` system variable. So, I've added `MAVEN_OPTS` with value `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1280m`. If I run `echo %MAVEN_OPTS%`, I see `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1280m`.

Now, if I try to run `mvn clean install`, I get:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

That's strange, because task manager says, that I have 5.9 Gb of available RAM. Why can this error be thrown? Why cannot it reserve the desired space? I'm using 32-bit JVM and Windows 8.

**UPDATE**: 64-bit JVM helped. I didn't think, that `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1280m` is too much for 32-bit JVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the configuration to the gwt-maven-plugin via

```
mvn -Dgwt.extraJvmArgs=-Xmx1280m clean install
```

see also http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html

You could also try to reduce the amount of memory:

> Could not reserve enough space for object heap

This sounds like the JVM can't reserve the desired space. Try -Xmx1024m or -Xmx768m.

If this also doesn't work, you could try to use a 64 bit JVM to compile the code.

Comment: Forgot to mention, that I've tried that. Both -Dgwt.extraJvmArgs=-Xmx1280m and -Dgwt.extraJvmArgs="-Xmx1280m", it didn't help.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that, and it didn't work. That's just not enough for this compilation. The main question is: why cannot it reserve the desired space? That's strange, because it's available.

Comment: can you try to use as 64bit jvm?

Comment: One of the apps, that I use, rely on 32-bit JVM, so I could, but it would be inconvenient. Also, I think 1280m shouldn't be a problem for 32-bit. Probably. :)

Comment: Yeah, well, 64-bit worked. Could you please include it in your answer? I'll mark it as the right one. BTW I thought the limit on 32-bit is about -Xmx1500m. So, do you know, why didn't -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1280m work? Was their sum used?